# Is it possible to set a direction for the Kendo DatePicker (Calendar)?

Tags: jquery, calendar, webforms, datepicker, kendo-ui

I have a calendar input on the bottom of a form.

When the user clicks on it, the calendar pops up bellow the input creating scroll bars.

Is there any way I can set the direction that a DatePicker will open?

For instance... left, right, above?

Here's my code:

```
$("#dpBirthDate").kendoDatePicker();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. You can edit the popup origin and position like this:

```
$("#date").kendoDatePicker({
    origin: "top left",
    position: "bottom left",
    animation: {
        open: {
            effects: "slideIn:up"
        }
    }
});
```

That *should* make it open upwards, but I can't seem to get it to work in a jsFiddle. Setting the `position` to `bottom` + anything always causes it to go back below the input box, as if `top` was specified. I can get it to show below or to the side, but not above. Not sure if it is a bug or what...

Comment: Why aren't origin and position in Kendo's documentation? http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker