# Display Kendo datepicker icon on the left

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

The Kendo datepicker control adds a calendar icon on the right side of the input. In general, that's fine, and it looks pretty good.

However, my style guide has icons on the *left* side of my form inputs. For example:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PayContribution, "{0:0.00}",
                     new { @class = "span10",
                     Value = @Model.PayContribution == 0m ?
                             "" : @Model.PayContribution.ToString() })
</div>
```

This would look rather silly to most users seeing something to the effect of "25.00            $" instead of "$25.00"

I'd rather not have all of my input with left-hand icons except for my datepickers with right-hand icons. Is there any way to shift Kendo's icon to the other side of the input box? Telerik's documentation doesn't indicate any such thing trivially, but the accepted answer to [Is it possible to set a direction for the Kendo DatePicker (Calendar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344241/is-it-possible-to-set-a-direction-for-the-kendo-datepicker-calendar) shows that there may be undocumented options. Hacking away at the DOM or CSS in the final rendering is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following CSS appears to have done the trick:

```
span[role=button].k-select {
    left: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231);
    border-radius: 0;
}

.k-picker-wrap {
    padding-left: 26px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite this CSS

```
  .k-picker-wrap {
      padding-left: 22px;
      padding-right: 0;
  }
  .k-select {
      left: 0;
```